# How to backup database so it retains character set and collation?

Tags: mysql

I have backup my database using this command

```
mysqldump -u username -ppasword dbname > /some_dir/somefilename.sql
```

After dumping I queried for the character set of the database and tables, found out database charset was changed from utf8 to latin1 same goes with some of it's tables. I would like to backup my database as is. How will I do that and what may have brought the changes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not particularly sure why that would have happened, but I know that you can change collation settings and export mySQL tables/databases in phpMyAdmin and maintain character encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Setting Database Character Set

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDb CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

For Unix/Linux or Wammp/Xammp Console

```
mysqldump -u username -p --default-character-set=utf8 -N database > backup.sql
mysql -u username -p --default-character-set=utf8 database < backup.sql
```

**GUI Help to make dump**

Backup using **[PHPmyadmin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database)**

Or

Change Character Encoding of Database before and after dump , checkout this article [Character Encoding Solution](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets)

Comment: "Backup using PHPmyadmin" is a vary bad suggeston! It has lots of bug and issues!